# How to do screensharing using TLKSimpleWebRTC

Tags: ios, webrtc

I am trying to use [TLKSimpleWebRTC](https://github.com/otalk/TLKSimpleWebRTC) of OTalk in my iOS app,It is easy to do video and audio chat, but I can't find the way to share my app screen using this SDK.

Is there anyone familiar with TLKSimpleWebRTC or WebRTC lib who can help me?

Comment: Do you find any solution for screen share using webRTC?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible due to the lack of a screen capture mechanism on iOS.